# How to put a description in an sql server database

Tags: sql-server

I use SQL Server Express 2012 and have multiple SQL Server databases and sometimes it gets difficult to find out which is which. So I want to put a description on each database. But I am not able to find any such option in the management studio. Has anybody faced this problem and knows the solution

Comment: You can't. :) as far as I know. But you can create your own data dectionary/table definations outside the sql server for your own reference.

Comment: Thanks youji.xii. I am doing the same as of now. But it is a pain. I wonder why is this simple thing not there. May be it is available in paid versions and has been crippled in express version.

Comment: Well, you can atleast create another table in the same database which contains your table definations. so everytime you're in SSMS you can just query it. :-)

Comment: My 2 cents: This is the reason you should **Always** use meaningful names for everything you code. I strongly recommend not to use abbreviations in any piece of code, nor in databases / tables / columns names. Remember that sometime in the future you (or worse, someone else) may need to read your code (even years after you wrote it). it's much easier to understand the code if your table name is `TeacherToClass` then `T2C`, for example.

Comment: I try to do that. But it gets just too long. Can't have each and every change and little detail in DBname. This is why now I am having a table in db for explanations an

Comment: You don't have to use full sentences, just make sure your code is readable. try to imagine what other developers can understand from your code and make it as easy as possible to understand. my longest variable name ever was 4 words long, it was worth every one of it's 17 characters :-)

Comment: Yes I understand. It is of course good and helps a lot but obviously can't cover a detailed explanation which is often required along with a proper name. The question is how to put that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got the answer now. We can use Extended properties.

Right click DBName in object explorer - > Properties -> Extended properties

In that I added "Description" under name and details under value. We can add more properties also if we want. Same can be done for Tables too

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mssm you can use "Registered Server", that way you can name and describe them , even sort them in groups